# AVG() of the quotient of two fields giving unexpected output in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQL table and I need to find the average of the quotient of two fields (`rating`, `position`) grouped by another field (`query_name`). I cannot make sense of why the following two queries don't give the same result:

Query 1:

```
SELECT query_name, AVG(rating/position) AS quality
FROM queries
GROUP BY query_name
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT query_name, AVG(rating*100/position)*100 AS quality
FROM queries
GROUP BY query_name
```

Here is the table:

```
+------------+-------------------+----------+--------+
| query_name | result            | position | rating |
+------------+-------------------+----------+--------+
| Dog        | Golden Retriever  | 1        | 5      |
| Dog        | German Shepherd   | 2        | 5      |
| Dog        | Mule              | 200      | 1      |
| Cat        | Shirazi           | 5        | 2      |
| Cat        | Siamese           | 3        | 3      |
| Cat        | Sphynx            | 7        | 4      |
+------------+-------------------+----------+--------+
```

This is the expected output:

```
Result table:
+------------+---------+
| query_name | quality |
+------------+---------+
| Dog        | 2.50    |
| Cat        | 0.66    |
+------------+---------+
```

However, Query 1 gives the following:

```
Result table:
+------------+---------+
| query_name | quality |
+------------+---------+
| Dog        | 2.33    |
| Cat        | 0.33    |
+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some databases do integer division, so `1/2` is `0` rather than `0.5`.  If this is the case, then your numbers will be off.

It is easily fixed. I just multiply by `1.0`:

```
SELECT query_name, AVG(rating * 1.0 / position) AS quality
```